# Using Python to match records across 2 files with many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, dataframe

I am new to Python. I have searched extensively for a solution to this problem without any success.

I have two csv files, File A and File B, per the below samples.

For each 'PO/ItemCode' combination in File A, I want to find a matching combination in File B and output a record to new csv file, File C.
If there are no matching records in File B, output a single record to File C with 'none/00' as the 'Ref/Line' fields. PO 1002 and 1005 are examples.

If the available quantity on a matched File B record is less that required in File A, write a File C record for the available quantity only and read File B again to find the next matching record. Once there are no more matching records, write a record to File C for the remaining (unmatched) File A quantity. PO 1006 is an example.

The total quantity for each 'PO/ItemCode' combination in File C will be the same as the combination total in File A.

There may be multiples of the same 'PO/ItemCode' combination in File A. These are treated as a single File A record having the accumulated total. PO 1003 is an example.

File A

```
PO        ItemCode   Invoice   QtyA
1001      ITEMA      2001      2
1001      ITEMB      2001      1
1002      ITEMB      2002      4
1003      ITEMA      2003      4
1003      ITEMA      2003      5
1004      ITEMA      2004      1
1005      ITEMB      2005      3
1006      ITEMA      2006      5
```

File B

```
PO        ItemCode   QtyB   Ref       Line
1000      ITEMA      2      8232      12
1001      ITEMA      2      8986      15
1001      ITEMB      2      8986      16
1003      ITEMA      7      8987      08
1004      ITEMA      3      8415      19
1006      ITEMA      2      8469      01
1006      ITEMA      1      8253      12
1008      ITEMB      3      8745      03
```

File C (output)

```
PO        ItemCode   Invoice   QtyC     Ref       Line
1001      ITEMA      2001      2        8986      15
1001      ITEMB      2001      1        8986      16
1002      ITEMB      2002      4        none      00
1003      ITEMA      2003      7        8987      08
1003      ITEMA      2003      2        none      00
1004      ITEMA      2004      1        8415      19
1005      ITEMB      2005      3        none      00
1006      ITEMA      2006      2        8469      01
1006      ITEMA      2006      1        8253      12
1006      ITEMA      2006      2        none      00
```

I've tried achieving this by reading File A records in a 'for loop' and using 'PO/ItemCode' as index to File B (read in as a DataFrame), but have been unable to match File B records beyond the first matched record. I've also been unable to find a method to recognize a File A record having the same 'PO/ItemCode' as the previous record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right: you can group dataframe A and sum the quantities A and then iterate over rows in dataframe B subtracting the quantities B from the total quantity A:

```py
df_A = df_A.groupby(["PO", "ItemCode"], as_index=False).agg(
    {"Invoice": "first", "QtyA": "sum"}
)
df_B = df_B.set_index(["PO", "ItemCode"])

out = []
for rowA in df_A.itertuples():
    if (rowA.PO, rowA.ItemCode) not in df_B.index:
        out.append(
            {
                "PO": rowA.PO,
                "ItemCode": rowA.ItemCode,
                "Invoice": rowA.Invoice,
                "QtyC": rowA.QtyA,
                "Ref": None,
                "Line": 0,
            }
        )
        continue

    qty_remaining = rowA.QtyA
    for rowB in df_B.loc[(rowA.PO, rowA.ItemCode)].itertuples():
        if qty_remaining - rowB.QtyB >= 0:
            n = rowB.QtyB
        else:
            n = qty_remaining

        out.append(
            {
                "PO": rowA.PO,
                "ItemCode": rowA.ItemCode,
                "Invoice": rowA.Invoice,
                "QtyC": n,
                "Ref": rowB.Ref,
                "Line": rowB.Line,
            }
        )

        qty_remaining -= n
        if qty_remaining == 0:
            break

    if qty_remaining > 0:
        out.append(
            {
                "PO": rowA.PO,
                "ItemCode": rowA.ItemCode,
                "Invoice": rowA.Invoice,
                "QtyC": qty_remaining,
                "Ref": None,
                "Line": 0,
            }
        )

out = pd.DataFrame(out)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
     PO ItemCode  Invoice  QtyC     Ref  Line
0  1001    ITEMA     2001     2  8986.0    15
1  1001    ITEMB     2001     1  8986.0    16
2  1002    ITEMB     2002     4     NaN     0
3  1003    ITEMA     2003     7  8987.0     8
4  1003    ITEMA     2003     2     NaN     0
5  1004    ITEMA     2004     1  8415.0    19
6  1005    ITEMB     2005     3     NaN     0
7  1006    ITEMA     2006     2  8469.0     1
8  1006    ITEMA     2006     1  8253.0    12
9  1006    ITEMA     2006     2     NaN     0
```

Comment: The subset created by code  "for rowB in df_B.loc[(rowA.PO, rowA.ItemCode)].itertuples():" includes ItemCode values which are not the same as rowA.ItemCode. The PO in the subset is always correctly matched to rowA.PO

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot like a Pandas merge left. The one thing I don't understand is why the output dataframe would be expected to have three entries for PO 1006.

```
import pandas as pd
fnA, fnB = (the, filenames)
aR, bR = [pd.read_csv(x), delim_whitespace=True) for x in (fnA, fnB)]
cR = aR.merge(bR, how="left") 
print(cR.to_markdown())
```

| PO | ItemCode | Invoice | QtyA | QtyB | Ref | Line |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | ITEMA | 2001 | 2 | 2 | 8986 | 15 |
| 1001 | ITEMB | 2001 | 1 | 2 | 8986 | 16 |
| 1002 | ITEMB | 2002 | 4 | nan | nan | nan |
| 1003 | ITEMA | 2003 | 4 | 7 | 8987 | 8 |
| 1003 | ITEMA | 2003 | 5 | 7 | 8987 | 8 |
| 1004 | ITEMA | 2004 | 1 | 3 | 8415 | 19 |
| 1005 | ITEMB | 2005 | 3 | nan | nan | nan |
| 1006 | ITEMA | 2006 | 5 | 2 | 8469 | 1 |
| 1006 | ITEMA | 2006 | 5 | 1 | 8253 | 12 |

Comment: The total output quantity has to be the same as the total input quantity. PO1006, ITEMA has total input quantity of 5 and must have total output quantity 5, so an additional output line for quantity 2 is required.