# Using Python to match records across 2 files with many-to-many relationship - Part 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two csv files, File A and File B, per the below samples.

For each 'PO/ItemCode' combination (per invoice) in File A, I want to find a matching 'PO/ItemCode' combination in File B and output a record to new csv file, File C.

The same 'PO/ItemCode' combination may exist in multiple invoices. Combination '1001/ITEMA' in invoices 2001 and 2007 is an example.

If there are no records in File B matching the 'PO/ItemCode' combination, output a single record to File C using 'none/00' as the 'Ref/Line' fields. Invoices 2002 and 2005 are examples.

If the available quantity on a matched File B record is less than required in File A, write a File C record for the available quantity only and read File B again to find the next matching record. Once there are no more matching records, write a record to File C for the remaining (unmatched) File A quantity using 'none/00' as the 'Ref/Line' fields. Invoices 2006 and 2007 are examples.

There may be multiples of the same 'PO/ItemCode' combination for a single invoice in File A. These are treated as a single File A record having the accumulated total. PO 1003 is an example, with the input treated as Invoice 2003, ITEMA, quantity 9.

The available quantity on File B records can only be used once. Subsequent File A records for the same 'PO/ItemCode' combination (different invoice number) can only use the remaining File B quantity, considering any previous matches. Combination '1001/ITEMA' in invoices 2001 and 2007 is an example.

The total quantity per 'PO/ItemCode' output to File C will be the same as the total quantity per 'PO/ItemCode' input in File A.

File A

```
Invoice   PO        ItemCode   QtyA
2001      1001      ITEMA      2
2001      1001      ITEMB      1
2002      1002      ITEMB      4
2003      1003      ITEMA      4
2003      1003      ITEMA      5
2004      1004      ITEMA      1
2005      1005      ITEMB      3
2006      1006      ITEMA      5
2007      1001      ITEMA      3
```

File B

```
PO        ItemCode   QtyB   Ref       Line
1000      ITEMA      2      8232      12
1001      ITEMA      4      8986      15
1001      ITEMB      2      8986      16
1003      ITEMA      7      8987      08
1004      ITEMA      3      8415      19
1006      ITEMA      2      8469      01
1006      ITEMA      1      8253      12
1008      ITEMB      3      8745      03
```

File C (output)

```
Invoice   PO        ItemCode   QtyC     Ref       Line
2001      1001      ITEMA      2        8986      15
2001      1001      ITEMB      1        8986      16
2002      1002      ITEMB      4        none      00
2003      1003      ITEMA      7        8987      08
2003      1003      ITEMA      2        none      00
2004      1004      ITEMA      1        8415      19
2005      1005      ITEMB      3        none      00
2006      1006      ITEMA      2        8469      01
2006      1006      ITEMA      1        8253      12
2006      1006      ITEMA      2        none      00
2007      1001      ITEMA      2        8986      15
2007      1001      ITEMA      1        none      00
```

My original question on this topic was asked (and answered) in a previous post [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77767984/using-python-to-match-records-across-2-files-with-many-to-many-relationship). Since then, the specifications have changed and I’m not sure how to modify the previous answer to produce the new requirements or if that is still the best method. My files are not large being a maximum of 2000 records.